Output diode selection to make 50Hz stick welder DC
I am fixing up a stick welder with a max output current of 240 A. DC welding has advantages in some jobs so I want to design/build a rectifier. My measured open circuit voltage is about 50 VAC, it does not change much when the current control front panel dial winds the magnetic shunts in and out. So the diodes do not need to be fast but the full wave bridge pack must be able to handle up to 240 A. My question is what about the voltage rating? Would 200 V diodes blow due to sparking causing inductive spikes? Should I snubb the diodes? Would oversnubbing make the arc harder to strike? What voltage rating would be sensible?

I'm impressed you are struggling over this. I do.MIG, TIG, and stick (SMAW) welding and love the work and over time getting better at it. But I decided to just buy the equipment than struggle over all the design details. I wanted to get on with the work. Look forward to seeing good answers. +1 for the question

@DrMoishePippik  This is just a "quibble" for interest. I understood what you intended by half-wave bridge. And/but: A center tapped two diode rectifier is a full wave rectifier (which I know you know). I think a better turn of phrase would be "half-bridge rectifier (tapped transformer)".

There are diodes that could easily handle that current and voltage., e.g., mouser.com/c/semiconductors/discrete-semiconductors/… amp diode&if - forward current=500 A and in.asenergi.com/products/diodes-stud/d171-500.html. They seem to be about US$60 each, and the lowest reverse voltage rating I saw was 600 V. Consider that you might need two diodes for a tapped transformer bridge or four for a full-wave bridge.
